# NetBeans and SQLite table communication issue?

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans

Hi I’m trying to connect to and SQLite table in java and it only outputs data from one method in the compiler output window code is below working method it commented to show which one is printing out the data please could you help.

[image]

```
//working methord which outputs data
@Override
    public String getReplyTimestamp(int RPLYID) {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Matt\\Documents\\message.sqlite");
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM MSG"; //Change message to relevent declaration
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()) { 
                System.out.println(rs.getString("MSG")+" "+rs.getString("URL"));
            }
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DBAccessImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DBAccessImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return "getReplyTimestamp";
    }


//Methoed which does not print
@Override
    public String getReply(int RPLYID) {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Matt\\Documents\\message.sqlite");
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM RPLY"; //Change message to relevent declaration
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("RPLY")+" "+rs.getString("TSTAMP"));
            }
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DBAccessImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DBAccessImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return "getReply";
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a rply table? Have you stepped through the method with the debugger?

Comment: Yes I have a rply table and have stepped through with the debugger.

Comment: This is not a NetBeans issue.  Please edit the title to your question so that it more accurately states your problem.

Comment: @MattTheCodeMan - When you use the debugger, are you able to inspect the contents of the ResultSet "rs"?

Comment: Hey yes I have a reply table and I had a look in to that and there was an issue  thanks for all the advice one of my friends advised me what had gone wrong and now its fixed thanks again for everything!